# Launch my app from Calendar Notes with Custom URL Scheme

Tags: iphone, url, calendar

I'm trying to get my application launched by clicking on a link in the Calendar's notes section, but I just can't do it ...

The URL schemes for *http://* and *mailto:* are working in the notes section (Safari and Mail are started, respectively), but *myapp://* does not work, and neither does *skype:*

*myapp://* is working fine when I put it into the address field in Safari, so the custom URL scheme did install successfully.

Is the Calendar only implementing some standard URL schemes and not able to recognize any installed custom URL scheme? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar, but I can't even get the iPad's Calendar app to display a URL placed in the "Notes" field (e.g. http : // www.apple.com) as a link, much less a custom URI scheme.  If I put the URL into the "URL" field of the calendar appointment, it works fine of course.  But the back-end calendars I'm testing (e.g. Google mail) seem to place "Description" content into the "Notes" field.  Have you found a way around this?  (either creating a custom field on the google calendar appointment that shows up as a URL in iOS, or a way to get the Note to display a link?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found it myself ...

Apparently it is not enough to just write

```
myapp://
```

but it has to be

```
myapp://<sometexthere>
```

in order for the calendar to recognize it as a custom URL scheme. Safari also accepts the version without text after the two slashes.

One never learns enough ...

Comment: You can open a custom URL Scheme from inside the calendar app with 1 large caveat. The calendar app only recognizes URL schemes that were registered BEFORE the calendar was opened. Meaning if your calendar is open when you install your app, the calendar will not recognize the URL scheme as a valid URL.

Answer (score 0):

I keep forgetting to open my *Science News* E-Zine and there's no other 'reminder'... so:

In CALENDAR I created a monthly-repeating event called: ScienceNewsOpen and it's ‘Alert’ is ‘Open File: **SCIENCE NEWS OPENER.APP’**

In **AUTOMATOR** I created that application which began as a Calendar Event but was saved as an app:

**FIND CALENDAR EVENTS** where **ALL** is true, "Date Starting" is "Today" and "Any Content" contains *Science News*.

**GET SPECIFIED URLs**, "Remove" the existing default Apple.com, "Add" ScienceNews.org

**DISPLAY WEBPAGES**:
The Science News Website opens in my default browser (FFox) in its own tab, i.e., not a new window once a month - but it can open any URL you put in the **Application** at any time you want to program into the **Calendar**.