# Can I launch an iOS app from the calendar?

Tags: ios, calendar

Is it possible to launch any of the apps I made directly from the calendar?
If I have a particular entry in my calendar can I link it to an app?

Comment: It may be possible to embed a link to your application in an ics file's notes...

Answer (score 1):

No it is not.
But as CodaFi stated, you could try to implement custom URL schemes in your app and note the appropriate url in the calendar event.

**Update:**
No, it doesn't work even with the url inside the calendar event because it doesn't recognizes it as a link.

**Update 2:**
I've found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513965/launch-my-app-from-calendar-notes-with-custom-url-scheme) with the same problem. Sadly it's not working for me, but i can test it only on iOS6 and it may be broken there.

Comment: yinkou, I haven't found a way to get a URL in the "Notes" field to render as a link either (at least not on an ipad).  The "URL" field will render as a link (including custom URI schemes like "fb://") but I haven't found a way to get this field set from outside the iCalendar iOS app (e.g. google calendar).

Comment: custom URL schemes will work in the notes section. You just have to restart the calendar app after the new url scheme is registered.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. The app you want to use needs to support URL schema. You must have some text after the schema:// though for Calendar to recognise. It works fine ios4+ (inc 6).

E.g. For Facebook profile you could use fb://me and it will load. Fb:// won't work.

Comment: jr19, do you know of a way to create a calendar appointment using an external program (google calendar, outlook, etc) in a way that will have a URL show up in the iOS Calendar's "URL" field (and therefore render as a link)?

Answer (score 0):

You can open a custom URL Scheme from inside the calendar app with 1 large caveat. The calendar app only recognizes URL schemes that were registered BEFORE the calendar was opened. Meaning if your calendar is open when you install your app, the calendar will not recognize the URL scheme as a valid URL.