# Can we pass some URI to android native calender app to launch our android app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-calendar

We are setting some calendar events from our android app now we want to pass some URI or Intent to calendar along with event data so that if user clicks on that link it will launch our app.

Already it has been implemented in iOS so same feature client want in android also.You can check this for [iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513965/launch-my-app-from-calendar-notes-with-custom-url-scheme).

Answer (score 0):

I have found following solution for Android API level 16 and above

1. First of all add following intent filter in manifest to one of your activity

> ```
> <intent-filter>
>     <action android:name="android.provider.calendar.action.HANDLE_CUSTOM_EVENT" />
>     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
>     <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/event" />
> </intent-filter>
> ```

2. Pass following values to calendar content resolver

> ```
>  ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
>  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
>  TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
>  values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startTimeInMilliSeconds);
>  values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endTimeInMilliSeconds);
>  values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());
>  values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
>  values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION,desc);
>  values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 3);
>  values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CUSTOM_APP_PACKAGE, "com.my.pkg");//your app package 
>  values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CUSTOM_APP_URI,"https://www.my.pkg.com/eventID/");
> ```

After creating a calendar event it will show your app icon and app name in details of the calendar event.

Known Issue : 
This solution is working on all google devices (Nexus devices) or any devices which have android os without any company customization (Moto g etc)

Comment: Please help me on this why I am not able to see on other devices.Thanks in advance.